# Invalid markup on table elements

Tags: html, css, html-table, dreamweaver

I created my table using Dreamweaver and it created all the heights and widths for me but when I passed it through the CSS validator, I have

> The width attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>
> The bgcolor attribute on the th element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>
> The height attribute on the th element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Basically, all the attributes on the th element they say that it is obsolete.

```
<table width="1108" border="1" id="table">
   <tr id="toprow">
     <th width="103" height="45" bgcolor="#000000" scope="row">Name</th>
     <th width="114" bgcolor="#000000">Type </th>
     <th width="104" bgcolor="#000000">Summoner Level</th>
     <th width="191" bgcolor="#000000">Maps</th>
     <th width="566" bgcolor="#000000">Description</th>
   </tr>
 <tr>
     <th height="120" scope="row"><p><img src="summonerspells/64px-Barrier.png" width="64" height="64" alt="barrier"></p>
     <p>Barrier</p></th>
     <td>Defense</td>
     <td>Level 6</td>
     <td><p>Summoner's Rift<br>
Twisted Treeline<br>
Crystal Scar<br>
Howling Abyss</p></td>
     <td>Shields your champion for 115-455 (depending on champion level) for 2     seconds.</td>
   </tr>

<tr>
     <th height="68" scope="row"><p><img src="summonerspells/Teleport.png" width="64" height="64" alt="teleport"></p>
     <p>Teleport</p></th>
     <td>Utility</td>
     <td>Level 2 </td>
     <td>summoners rift</td>
     <td>After casting for 4 seconds, teleports your champion to target allied minion, turret, or ward.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th height="68" scope="row"><p><img src="summonerspells/Clarity.png" width="64" height="64" alt="clarity"></p>
     <p>Clarity</p></th>
     <td>Utility</td>
     <td>Level 1</td>
     <td>Summoner's Rift<br>
       Twisted Treeline<br>
       Crystal Scar<br>
     Howling Abyss</td>
     <td>Restores 40% of your champion's maximum Mana. Also restores allies for 40% of their maximum Mana</td>
   </tr>
```

This is part of code, my table is very long so it would be very tiring to read. If you know how to fix the height thing, I can work it out on the rest of my codes.

Comment: That's what you get from using a [wysiwyg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor.

Comment: Why don't you follow the validator's good advice and **use CSS instead?**

Comment: i do not know how to use CSS >.< i mean i know, but i am not familiar with table styling

Comment: How does this involve jQuery? \*removes tag\*

Comment: haha >.< i thought that i would draw more ppl to the qns since jquery is related to html

Comment: Table styling is just like any other kind of styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {width:1108px;border:1px solid #999;}
    table tr#toprow th {height:120px;background-color:#000;}
</style>
```

You don't really need heights on the other rows because your images will stretch them out with their image heights.

```
<table id="table">
   <tr id="toprow">
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Type </th>
     <th>Summoner Level</th>
     <th>Maps</th>
     <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
 <tr>
     <th scope="row"><p><img src="summonerspells/64px-Barrier.png" width="64" height="64" alt="barrier"></p>
     <p>Barrier</p></th>
     <td>Defense</td>
     <td>Level 6</td>
     <td><p>Summoner's Rift<br>
Twisted Treeline<br>
Crystal Scar<br>
Howling Abyss</p></td>
     <td>Shields your champion for 115-455 (depending on champion level) for 2     seconds.</td>
   </tr>

<tr>
     <th scope="row"><p><img src="summonerspells/Teleport.png" width="64" height="64" alt="teleport"></p>
     <p>Teleport</p></th>
     <td>Utility</td>
     <td>Level 2 </td>
     <td>summoners rift</td>
     <td>After casting for 4 seconds, teleports your champion to target allied minion, turret, or ward.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th scope="row"><p><img src="summonerspells/Clarity.png" width="64" height="64" alt="clarity"></p>
     <p>Clarity</p></th>
     <td>Utility</td>
     <td>Level 1</td>
     <td>Summoner's Rift<br>
       Twisted Treeline<br>
       Crystal Scar<br>
     Howling Abyss</td>
     <td>Restores 40% of your champion's maximum Mana. Also restores allies for 40% of their maximum Mana</td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have been using an HTML5 validator, i.e. experimental software that checks against some HTML5 draft, such as http://validator.w3.org (CSS validators do not issue messages about HTML markup).

First, you should decide whether you care. Markup features like those that the HTML5 validator complains about are old-fashioned and often clumsy, but they work (and HTML5 drafts contain requirements on browsers to keep supporting them). Replacing them by CSS would mostly be a matter of theoretical purity, and you might not afford it, especially if you intend to maintain the page using tools that produced this markup. Moreover, any cleanup of code carries the risk of causing problems rather than solving them: you might make mistakes, and you might unintentionally change the rendering.

If you really want to go on, you might check my informal page [Mapping presentational HTML to CSS](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html2css.html) and, if you are brave, section [Rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendering) in HTML5 CR (which describes more formally how browsers are expected to map presentational HTML elements and attributes to CSS.

In particular,

- the `width` attribute is naturally mapped to a CSS property with the same name, e.g. `#table { width: 1108px }
- the `bgcolor` attribute maps to the `background-color` property
- the `height` attribute maps to the CSS property with the same name.

A simple approach is to replace the attributes by CSS code inside `style` attributes, e.g.

```
<th style="width: 103px; height: 45px; background-color: #000000" 
    scope="row">Name</th>
```

It is questionable whether this is an improvement. It would be better to use an external style sheet and put the rules there. But then you would need suitable selectors, and for this, good understanding of CSS basics.

And there is really nothing to be gained in practice. It’s boring, error-prone, and generally unproductive to “fix” the HTML code generated by authoring tools. Instead, for future projects, try to find tools that generate reasonably modern, readable, and robust HTML and CSS code.